# Perl Hashes: $hash{key} vs $hash->{key}

Tags: perl, reference, hashmap, key, dereference

Perl newb here, sorry for a silly question, but googling `->` for a coding context is tough... Sometimes, I will access a hash like this: `$hash{key}` and sometimes that doesn't work, so I access it like this `$hash->{key}`. What's going on here? Why does it work sometimes one way and not the other?

Comment: http://stevieb-tech.blogspot.com/2012/04/use-perl-guide-to-references-part-1.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case `%hash` is a hash, and in the second case, `$hash` is a reference to a hash (= hash reference), thus you need different notations. In the second case `->` dereferences `$hash`.

**EXAMPLES:**

```
# %hash is a hash:
my %hash = ( key1 => 'val1', key2 => 'val2');

# Print 'val1' (hash value for key 'key1'):
print $hash{key1}; 

# $hash_ref is a reference to a hash:
my $hash_ref = \%hash;

# Print 'val1' (hash value for key 'key1', where the hash 
# in pointed to by the reference $hash_ref):
print $hash_ref->{key1}; 

# A copy of %hash, made using dereferencing:
my %hash2 = %{$hash_ref}

# $hash_ref is an anonymous hash (no need for %hash).
# Note the { curly braces } :
my $hash_ref = { key1 => 'val1', key2 => 'val2' };

# Access the value of anonymous hash similarly to the above $hash_ref:
# Print 'val1':
print $hash_ref->{key1};
```

**SEE ALSO:**

perlreftut: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html